# How to run schedule task in c# blazor every 30 second

Tags: c#, blazor, server-side, binance

I am writing a blazor server side application. I have like **100 Binance API** or more to work with. How can I run a scheduled task that will monitor each API on given amount of time. Or is there any better way to approach approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a background service. Nothing to do with Blazor, just Asp.Net:

It's just one line in the Startup class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   ...       
   services.AddHostedService<MyBackgroundService>();
}
```

and then [implement your own MyBackgroundService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) with a loop or a Timer.

Comment: thank you, I've also found another solution which is hangfire. it's pretty straightforward it also provide dashboard.

Comment: Yes, it looks a little more involved then just a worker, depends on what you need.

Comment: Most likely your web application will go into sleep mode after a period of time (in both cases background service or hangfire). Some additional configuration on IIS (application pool) is required to keep your application always alive.