# How can I disable some mysql dataset for a user specified time frame in my webapp and restore it automatically

Tags: mysql, temporary-files

i am developing a web app to admininstrate a mysql database.
So far this work is making a good progress.

Now i need a feature to deactivate some datasets for a time frame the user can choose in the web app.

After deactivating: The dataset shouldn´t be active in the database, but the user should be able to restore the dataset anytime. (i will create a page: "Deactivated")

If the user doesnt restore the dataset. Then the dataset should be restored automatically when the specified time frame by the user is over.

How can i build this feature and disable some dataset for a time frame and restore it again after?

hope u understand and can help me ;)

i mean with dataset=rows in a database

Comment: What "Precisely" does deactivate a dataset mean

Comment: @RiggsFolly i need to take some datasets out of the database to exempt them from a verification. To do this, they should be disabled in my web app. did this answer the question ??

Comment: No! Do you mean you want to physically remove one or more ___TABLES___ from the schema for some time and then restore them

Comment: @RiggsFolly No not the whole Table, but some rows from a Table.

Comment: Simple answer is NO! But if you tried to describe what you are trying to achieve and why, then someone may be able to make a suggestion to assist you

Comment: @RiggsFolly is my problem clear now?

Comment: No, it is not clear at all what you want! The problem is that your are asking us to help you with a feature, as opposed to help you with a specific programming problem! To your question as it stands there are two possible answers: A) cheeky one saying you can build this feature by writing the appropriate code B) an answer that effectively designs the feature for you, possibly with some code. The former is out of line, the latter means we would your work and is unlikely to fly here.

Comment: Mysql does not have the concept of datasets, nor whether any data within it is active or inactive. These are concepts bespoke to your app. You need to explain these concepts and you also need to ask a specific programming related question.

Comment: @Shadow thanks for your answer, i will edit my question and hope they will understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot solve this on the MySQL level. This database engine doesn't recognize data sets and time-framing them as you describe (As far as I know).

Because of that, you have to solve this on the application level.
I don't know what the structure of your database is, so let's say you store your data in the table named `dataset`.

---

**1. part: Deactivated**

> I need a feature to deactivate some datasets

A potential solution here is to add a flag to the table `dataset`. And let's name it `active`. See [MySQL Bool](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/other-vendor-data-types.html).

For this page

> I will create a page: "Deactivated"
> you can fetch data by this query

```
SELECT *
FROM dataset
WHERE active = false;
```

The consequence of this update (adding flag).
You should update all existing queries with this addition to the where clause: `WHERE ... AND active = true`.
For example, when you fetching data for a user with ID 10, the query is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dataset
WHERE user_id = 10
    AND active = true;
```

**2. part: Time frame**

For this part, I propose to use another column in the `dataset` table - let's name it `activation_date`.

So, what is an idea here?
In this column, you store when that row should become active again.

For activation data, you need a job-scheduling framework. And each midnight, a background process executes this query.

```
UPDATE dataset
SET active = true
WHERE activation_date >= CURRENT_DATE();
```

Of course, you can use some more granular time; or activate your job at another time. It depends on the requirements.

Note for the job-scheduling framework. For Java, it could be [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org). I am not sure which programming language you use; I guess, it has an equivalent tool like Quartz.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am using C# with Blazor, do u a framework for this?

Comment: I am not sure what your question is. I guess, it is "do you know a framework for this?"
After a quick search, I found Quarz.NET; and this SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65899465/how-to-run-schedule-task-in-c-sharp-blazor-every-30-second

Comment: Be aware that you may need to modify some `INDEXes` to maintain performance.

Comment: @RickJames You are right 100%. I haven't pay attention to those details.